# Does anyone use DbEnumerator

Tags: .net, ado.net

I've only just come across the `DbEnumerator` class, which exists since .NET 1.x and is mainly intended for databinding support.  Reflector reveals that internally it maintains a Hashtable for lookup of field names, so could potentially be more efficient when iterating over a large result set and accessing fields by name.

I often use the following pattern when iterating over an `IDataReader`:

```
// Factory method to create entity from IDataRecord
private static MyEntity GetMyEntityFromRecord(IDataRecord record)
{
    return new MyEntity(
        (string) record["Field1"]
        , ...
    );
}

// Extension method to enumerate an IDataReader
static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> Enumerate(this IDataReader reader)
{
    foreach(IDataRecord record in reader)
    {
        yield return record;
    }
}

IList<MyEntity> GetMyEntities(...)
{
    ...
    using(IDataReader reader = ...)
    {
        return reader.Enumerate().Select(x => GetMyEntityFromRecord(x)).ToList();
    }
    ...
}
```

And it seems that by using `DbEnumerator` in my `Enumerate` method I would get the cached field name lookup table for free:

```
static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> Enumerate(this IDataReader reader)
{
    DbEnumerator dbEnumerator = new DbEnumerator(reader);
    while (dbEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return (IDataRecord) dbEnumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

Any comments on whether `DbEnumerator` is likely to be beneficial or otherwise in the general case?  On first sight it looks attractive, despite being an old .NET 1.x implementation (returns a non-generic enumerator; uses a Hashtable rather than a generic dictionary internally), as it means there's no longer a need to access fields by index for performance reasons.

There is an internal overhead of instantiation of DataRecordInternal instances on each iteration which might outweigh the benefit of cached field name lookup in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that it's against the principle of least surprise to have an extension method `Enumerate()` that silently wraps the reader with a `DbEnumerator` internally.  So I've implemented it with an overload that allows a caller to explicitly opt-in to using the `DbEnumerator`.  Next time I'm playing with large result sets I might try to do some benchmarking.

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> Enumerate(this IDataReader reader)
{
    return Enumerate(reader, false);
}

public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> Enumerate(this IDataReader reader, bool useDbEnumerator)
{
    if (useDbEnumerator)
    {
        DbEnumerator dbEnumerator = new DbEnumerator(reader);
        while (dbEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return (IDataRecord)dbEnumerator.Current;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return reader;
        }
    }
}
```